Ubuntu Livepatch - Weird Continous Problems
I have this problem since I installed Ubuntu few weeks ago. I read through few similar post and none was exactly they way I experience a problem.
Very frequently (50% of days) when I turn on my PC and login to Ubuntu there is a Livepatch error saying "An error occurred while checking for livepatch updates".
I check status page of Cannoncial services - all operable. I tried to diable Livepatch in Software Updates Settings, but it gave me an error, something about not being able to disable Livepatch, but the switch for Livepatch setting went into "off" position and Livepatch icon disappeared from taskbar. So after googling I enabled it with sudo pro enable livepatch - SUCCESS. Then I checked the status with canonical-livepatch status --verbose and got following result:
:~$ canonical-livepatch status --verbose
last check: 15 seconds ago
kernel: 6.8.0-35.35-generic
server check-in: failed: livepatch check failed: error response with status 502 (Bad Gateway): "<html><body><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>\nThe server returned an invalid or incomplete response.\n</body></html>\n\n"
kernel state: ✓ kernel series 6.8 is covered by Livepatch
patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.8.0-35.35-generic
tier: updates (Free usage; This machine beta tests new patches.)
machine id: e54e3714036646619d60e97971ceaaa6
client version: 10.8.3
architecture: amd64
cpu model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
boot time: 3 minutes ago

I tried to disable and re-enable Livepatch again right away. Diable through GUI went with the same effect - "cannot disable livepatch". Then I tried via console sudo pro disable livepatch and got this:
Livepatch is not currently enabled - nothing to do.
See: sudo pro status

So I checked pro status with sudo pro status and got
SERVICE          ENTITLED  STATUS       DESCRIPTION
anbox-cloud      yes       disabled     Scalable Android in the cloud
esm-apps         yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications
esm-infra        yes       enabled      Expanded Security Maintenance for Infrastructure
landscape        yes       disabled     Management and administration tool for Ubuntu
livepatch        yes       disabled     Canonical Livepatch service
realtime-kernel* yes       disabled     Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated


Then I tried enabling Livepatch again with sudo pro enable livepatch, but this time it didn't let me:
One moment, checking your subscription first
An unexpected error occurred: Remote end closed connection without response
For more details, see the log: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
If you think this is a bug, please run: ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools

I tried again with different error:
One moment, checking your subscription first
Installing Livepatch
Setting up Livepatch
Unable to enable Livepatch: Failed running command '/snap/bin/canonical-livepatch enable <REDACTED>' [exit(1)]. Message: Could not retrieve client information.: GET request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/e54e3714036646619d60e97971ceaaa6/info" failed

Could not enable Livepatch.

I don't know what to do next, it feels so random that it works half of the time when I use PC and half it does not... Anything I could ran to debug/solve the problem?
PS. 5 minutes later I did sudo pro enable livepatch and it was successful with errors...
One moment, checking your subscription first
Installing Livepatch
Setting up Livepatch
Livepatch enabled
An unexpected error occurred: Remote end closed connection without response
For more details, see the log: /var/log/ubuntu-advantage.log
If you think this is a bug, please run: ubuntu-bug ubuntu-advantage-tools


This is not an issue that can be addressed by the volunteers on this site. You need to contact  Canonical for support of the Livepatch product.

If you turn off your PC every night, I don't see the point of using Livepatch at all.

Hmm good point @OrganicMarble, one less thing to care about : )
